# How to calculate area in raster data in ArcGIS 9.3

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-9.3

I run a supervised classification on a Spot image and now want to calculate the area of different classes without converting to shapefile, because converting to polygon creates too much polygons which is very impossible to calculate area from them?

Answer (score 2):

with a categorical raster data, you can build the [raster attribute table](http://webhelp.esri.com/ARCGISDESKTOP/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Build_Raster_Attribute_Table_%28Data_Management%29) of your raster. Once this is done, open your table (right click on the layer) and you will see the count of the pixels. Multiply by the area of your pixels and you have a good approximation of the area of each class.

Comment: Note that it is not impossible to calculate the area based on a lot of polygons...

Comment: One would not expect more than a few million polygons from a classified SPOT image. If you convert it directly into an ArcSDE geodatabase  then you already have the areas (you can then use summary stat). So it is not "impossible" (with file gdb, it would also work) but I agree the asker is right that it is not the best method.

Comment: It would be well worth enhancing your answer with that additional information rather than tacking it on in comments.